# Access an element in a template after a transition with $location.path

Tags: angularjs

On a template that belong to a certain route I want to click on a link or button that calls a method in the scope and from there I will transition to a new route and look for an element on the template for the new route. Basically something like this:

```
    app.controller('SomeController', function SomeController($scope, $location) {
        $scope.goToOverview = function (showModal) {
            $location.path("overview/basic");

            if(showModal){
               $('#basicModal').modal('toggle');
            }
        };
    });
```

The problem is that when I reach the jQuery selector, the template for the "overview/basic" route has not been loaded yet so the element is not found.

How can this be solved?

Thank you.

Comment: `> How can this be solved?` Maybe by defining another controller for `overview/basic` and pass in the `showModal` as a state parameter?

Comment: Try to put in the run block $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',function (event, toState) {} than you check like toState.name do broadcast or somthing like that

Comment: @fardjad That's what we are trying to avoid, to not put too many things on the url.

Comment: @SergioRomero Oh I see, Then you could broadcast an event or define a service and use it on both controllers.

Comment: Sergio, If you have another controller on overview/basic template you can also use $rootScope to perform a communication between controllers.

Comment: @fardjad I'm afraid I'm having a hard time visualizing the solution, particularly how to have the overview/basic controller subscribe to an event that is created on the "SomeController" controller. Would you mind showing an example in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As [requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848673/access-an-element-in-a-template-after-a-transition-with-location-path?noredirect=1#comment34856684_22848673), [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZFr6) is an example of broadcasting an event from one controller and catching it in another controller:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="OneCtrl">
        <form>
            <input type="text" ng-model="msg"></input>
            <input type="submit" ng-click="send(msg)" value="Broadcast"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="TwoCtrl">
        <p>Message from OneCtrl: {{ msg }}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('OneCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.send = function (msg) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('one_msg', {
            msg: msg
        });
    };
});

app.controller('TwoCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('one_msg', function (event, data) {
        $scope.msg = data.msg;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually the communication between the controllers worked when I used $emit instead of $broadcast but it still did not solve the original problem which is to display the modal window by executing $('#basicModal').modal('toggle'). The template is still not loaded so the jQuery returns and empty result.