# AngularJS $emit does not fire the event after added code to unregister

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events

I just found out how to communicate between controllers using `$broadcast` and `$emit`, tried it in my POC and it worked, sort of, the original problem described in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848673/access-an-element-in-a-template-after-a-transition-with-location-path) is still not solved but now I have another question, the event is being registered multiple times so I am trying to unregister it the way I've seen it in multiple posts here on SO but now the event won't fire. The code is as follows:

```
tabsApp.controller('BasicOverviewController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    var unbind = $rootScope.$on('displayModal', function (event, data) {
        if (data.displayModal) {
            alert("I want to display a modal!");
            var modal = $('#basicModal');
            modal.modal('toggle');
        }
    });
    
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        unbind();
    });        
});

tabsApp.controller('SportsController', function SportsController($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    $scope.goToOverview = function (showModal) {
        $location.path("overview/basic");
        $rootScope.$emit('displayModal', { displayModal: showModal })
    };
});
```

If I remove the

> var unbind = ...

the event fires and I can see the alert. As soon as I add the code to unregister the event, the code is never fired. How can the two things work together?

Comment: So, in above script, which one is your unregister event? I can't find it.

Comment: @IqbalFauzi I understood that the $scope.$on('$destroy'....) is what unregisters the event. I could be missing stuff, hence the question, this is all the code in play.

Comment: `$destroy` event will only get called when the scope destroyed, which mean your `displayModal` will get registered on scope destroyed. @ZackArgyle answer below is the right way to register and unregister event as i know.

Answer (score 1):

Could you just pull out unbind into its own function, and use it in both like this?

```
tabsApp.controller('BasicOverviewController', function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
    var unbind = function (event, data) {
        if (data.displayModal) {
            alert("I want to display a modal!");
            var modal = $('#basicModal');
            modal.modal('toggle');
        }
    };

    $rootScope.$on('displayModal', unbind);
    $scope.$on('$destroy', unbind);
});
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. The event is not being unregistered so each time I try it I have one extra alert.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but my guess would be that the `BasicOverviewController` isn't being persisted and it's scope is being destroyed before the `SportsController` gets a chance to utilize it. Without a working example, I can't deduce much more. If you want to maintain this on `$rootScope` then a possible pattern would be:

```js
if (!$rootScope.displayModalDereg) {
  $rootScope.displayModalDereg = $rootScope.$on('displayModal', function (event, data) {
    if (data.displayModal) {
        alert("I want to display a modal!");
        var modal = $('#basicModal');
        modal.modal('toggle');
    }
});
```

This also allows you to check and see if there is an event registered so you can dereg it if needed.

```js
if ($rootScope.displayModalDereg) {// this event has been registered
  $rootScope.displayModalDereg();
  $rootScope.dispalyModalDereg = undefined;
}
```

I would heavily suggested creating a displayModal directive that persists all of this instead of maintaining it on `$rootScope`. Obviously you would still `$emit`, or better yet, `$broadcast` from $`rootScope`, just not persist the dereg function there.

Here is an example of a modal directive I once wrote:

```js
/**
 *
 * Modal Directive
 */

'use strict';

(function initModalDrtv(window) {
  var angular = window.angular,
      app = window.app;

  angular.module(app.directives).directive('modalDrtv', [
    '$rootScope',
    function modalDrtv($rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: '/templates/modal.html',
        replace: true,
        compile: function modalCompileFn(tElement, tAttrs) {
          return function modalLinkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.show = false;

            scope.options = {
              'title': '',
              'message': '',
              'markup': undefined,
              'buttons': {
                showCancel: false,
                showSecondary: false,
                secondaryAction: '',
                primaryAction: 'Ok'
              },
              'responseName': ''
            };

            scope.respond = function(response) {
              var r = '';
              if (response === 1) {
                r = scope.options.buttons.primaryAction;
              } else if (response === 2) {
                r = scope.options.buttons.secondaryAction;
              } else {
                r = response;
              }
              $rootScope.$broadcast(scope.options.responseName, r);
              scope.show = false;
            };

            scope.$on('initIrpModal', function(event, data) {
              if (angular.isUndefined(data)) throw new Error("Data missing from irp modal event");
              scope.options.title = data.title;
              scope.options.message = data.message;
              scope.options.buttons.showCancel = data.buttons.showCancel;
              scope.options.buttons.showSecondary = data.buttons.showSecondary;
              scope.options.buttons.secondaryAction = data.buttons.secondaryAction;
              scope.options.buttons.primaryAction = data.buttons.primaryAction;
              scope.options.responseName = data.responseName;
              scope.show = true;
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]);
})(window);
```

This directive utilizes one modal and let's anything anywhere in the app utilize it. The registered event lives on its isolate scope and therefore is destroyed when the modal's scope is destroyed. It also is configured with a response name so that if a user response is needed it can broadcast an event, letting the portion of the app that initialized the modal hear the response.